# Scheduling a job in oracle to drop and create table

Tags: oracle, dblink

I am trying to DROP and CREATE a table using a scheduled job. How to do it please?

```
DROP TABLE REGISTRATION;

CREATE TABLE REGISTRATION AS
SELECT *
FROM REGISTRATION_MV@D3PROD_KMDW
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps you are looking for a materialized view instead of the table?

```
create materialized view registration as
select *
from registration_mv@d3prod_kmdw
```

and then refresh it in job

```
dbms_mview.refresh('REGISTRATION');
```

This is much better than dropping and creating the table because PL/SQL objects will become invalid after dropping the table. With mview it will be silent and without harm.

Comment: I agree. Although, technically this is not the answer for the question asked, it is highly probable that this is what Neels wants. Maybe (s)he'd like to elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `DBMS_SCHEDULER` to schedule jobs in Oracle.

Refer to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedadmin006.htm) for how to create a sample scheduler job

Answer (score 1):

Don't drop and recreate the table. If you do this on a regular basis you will end up with a huge number of items in your recycle bin, which can lead to problems. Also as above you can invalidate pl/sql when you drop objects, and can break your app if they fail to recompile.

Instead you should truncate the table to delete all rows, and then repopulate it:

> truncate table registration;
>
> insert into registration (select * from registration_mv@D3PROD_KMDW);